# Java Mockito PotentialStubbingProblem: Strict stubbing argument mismatch error

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have the method bellow that i need to test using mockito:

```
public User update(project.models.domain.User userObject) {

        var user = validateIfUserExists(userObject);
        var agroupmentFoundInDatabase = validateIfUserExistsInAgroupmentTable(userObject);
        
        User result = userRepository.save(user);
        
        if(!agroupmentFoundInDatabase.getProfileCode().equals(userObject.getProfile().getCode())) {     
            userUnionProfileRepository.delete(agroupmentFoundInDatabase);
            userUnionProfileRepository
            .save(UserUnionProfile.builder().userCode(userObject.getId())
                    .profileCode(userObject.getProfile().getCode()).build());
        }

        return result;
    }
```

This is my test method:

```
@Test
public void update() throws Exception {

br.com.rd.productmodels.product.domain.User userObject = mockUser();

User user = User.builder().code(135).description("test").build();
when(repository.findById(any())).thenReturn(Optional.of(user));
when(mapper.map(userObject, User.class)).thenReturn(user);

UserUnionProfile agroupmentObject = UserUnionProfile.builder().userCode(135).profileCode(12).build();
when(userUnionProfileRepository.findById(any())).thenReturn(Optional.of(agroupmentObject));
when(mapper.map(agroupmentObject,UserUnionProfile.class)).thenReturn(agroupmentObject);

when(repository.save(any())).thenReturn(user);
        
User entity = service.update(userObject);

verify(repository).save(any());
assertNotNull(entity);
}
```

But when I run my test, it gives me the following message:

```
PotentialStubbingProblem: Strict stubbing argument mismatch. Please check:
 - this invocation of 'map' method:
    mapper.map(Optional[UserUnionProfile(userCode=135, profileCode=12)],class project.domain.UserUnionProfile
);
```

I tried using `@MockitoSettings(strictness = Strictness.LENIENT)`. The error goes away but my result is null after the line `mapper.map(Optional[UserUnionProfile(userCode=135, profileCode=12)],class project.domain.UserUnionProfile` is executed. What should I do?

#More details about the update method that I'm trying to test. Here are the other methods called:

```
private User validateIfUserExists(project.models.domain.User userObject) {

    var user = userRepository.findById(userObject.getId());

    if (user.isEmpty()) {
        throw new UserNotFoundException(userObject.getId());
    }

    return mapper.map(userObject, User.class);
}

private UserUnionProfile validateIfUserExistsInAgroupmentTable(project.models.domain.User userObject) {

        var agroupmentObject = userUnionProfileRepository.findById(userObject.getId());

        if (agroupmentObject.isEmpty()) {
            throw new AgroupmentNotFoundException(userObject.getId());
        }

        return mapper.map(agroupmentObject, UserUnionProfile.class);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test should pass if you called:

```java
when(mapper.map(Optional.of(agroupmentObject), UserUnionProfile.class)).thenReturn(agroupmentObject);
```

instead of:

```java
when(mapper.map(agroupmentObject, UserUnionProfile.class)).thenReturn(agroupmentObject);
```

because in `validateIfUserExistsInAgroupmentTable()` you don't map a `UserUnionProfile` but an `Optional<UserUnionProfile>`.

However, I think that what you actually want is to change the method's implementation and map the actual content of the `Optional`, rather than the `Optional` itself:

```java
return mapper.map(agroupmentObject.get(), UserUnionProfile.class);
```